# How to remove subview from memory, when returning to main view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Suppose, I have a mainview, when I click on a button it will load a subview and let that subview starts the flashlight(LED) and then when I return to main view, it will release the sub view and shuts down the flashlight(LED)

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [self setView:[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease]];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // If torch supported, add button to toggle flashlight on/off
    if ([device hasTorch] == YES)
    {  
        // Create an AV session
        AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

        // Create device input and add to current session
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
        [session addInput:input];

        // Create video output and add to current session
        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        [session addOutput:output];

        // Start session configuration
        [session beginConfiguration];
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

        // Set torch to on
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
        [session commitConfiguration];

        // Start the session
        [session startRunning];

        // Keep the session around
        [self setAVSession:session];

        [output release];

    }
}
```

Now, when I close the subview it should release it from memory and stops the flashlight.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self autorelease];
    [AVSession stopRunning];
    [AVSession release], AVSession = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

But this viewDidUnload thing is not working, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How do you return to main view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you are retaining the view controller, and it's deciding to keep the view in memory just in case your app decides to display it again (this is the caching that Caleb mentions in the comment). Just because a view is not visible doesn't mean it will get unloaded.

If you have a memory leak (and here I mean the VC), obviously it makes sense to fix it.

However, I think your best option for enabling and disabling the flashlight is to do so in viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear (or their ..will.. variants).

Comment: A view controller doesn't normally unload its view unless there's a memory warning.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you misunderstand the purpose of [`-viewDidLoad`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload).

`-viewDidUnload` is only called in low memory situations when the system is trying to free up memory. In that case, inactive view controllers will release their views and call `-viewDidUnload` so that you can release any view-related resources.

Do not count on `-viewDidUnload` being called when the view controller becomes inactive or when the view controller is released.

Your view controller presumably knows when the AVSession should be ended, and it can end the session whenever it figures that out.

By the way, it's a good thing that your `-viewDidUnload` never ran; the call to `[self autorelease]` would probably have led to a crash. Why are you doing that? The code you've shown is part of a view controller. I don't know what the name of that class is, so I'll imagine that it's `FlashlightViewController`. Presumably, some other view controller is instantiating FlashlightViewController and somehow making it active, like this:

```
FlashlightViewController *fvc = [[FlashlightViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc];
[fvc release];
```

Here, the navigation controller will have retained `fvc` when it was pushed, and the controller that created fvc releases it because it no longer needs its reference to the new controller. When the flashlight controller has finished its work and is popped off the navigation stack, the navigation controller will release it. Since no other object has retained the flashlight controller, it will automatically be deallocated. When that happens, it'll release its view, and since no other object has retained the view, the view will also be deallocated.

The details of your situation might be different, but the idea is always the same: both view controller and view will be removed from memory when the view controller has been released.

Comment: Then any other way to remove subview from memory.

Comment: Then any other way to remove subview from memory.

Comment: Why tie the AVSession business to whether or not the view is in memory? A view controller normally keeps its view in memory unless there's a reason not to, just as it defers loading the view until it's needed. If you want to end the session when the view disappears, use -viewWillDisappear or -viewDidDisappear, and the corresponding -view[Will|Did]Appear to create the session.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. 

But, would love to know if their is a way to remove subview from memory, as opening many subview will lead to slowdown of App and will result in crash.

While testing with Instruments I didn't found out any memory leaks.

Comment: Added some explanation above. In a nutshell, all you have to do to deallocate the view is to make sure that it has been released. If the view is managed by a view controller, the view controller will release it when it is itself deallocated, so all you really need to do is manage the view controller.